# getSupportLoaderManager() use same ids in different fragments?

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-loadermanager, android-cursor, android-support-library

I am making a viewPager in a FragmentActivity with multiple ListFragments. In order to populate the different listviews i get the LoaderManager and initiliaze in the loader. I wanted to have a unique LoaderManager for each fragment, however, fragments don't have a getSupportLoaderManager() method so i need to call the parent fragment activity:

```
getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager()
```

The problem with this approach that my Loaders id in different fragments conflicts with each others. It can get a little cumbersome when you already have multiple loaders id in one fragment. So is there a way to get an unique LoaderManager for each fragment, instead of calling the parent one? I basically want to be able to use the same id on multiple fragments.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need the same ID ? Can't you just give them a different IDs ? Yes there is coupling between fragments and activities, in different forms, and this is maybe the most sneaky one.

Comment: Well thats what i am doing now. But i am using many ids for each fragment and it can get pretty confusing. I often crash my app because of this. I just want to start from 0 on each fragment. Is not really a necessity but it would make my code cleaner and easier to read

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be too long a comment, but I continu our discussion within the comments of your question.

You should take it the other way around : live with the fact that the IDs are local to an activity, not to a fragment.

Yes, there is poor coupling between fragments and activities. Mostly call backs from fragments link the fragment to an activity (even when using an interface it's not that clean), and for passing arguments from an activity to a fragment : you must use a static factory method to both build the fragment and set its arguments via setArgs.

And your question is all about such a coupling issue : loaders IDs in each fragment of an activity should not overlap over the IDs used by all other fragments. That's a coupling constraint as well, as we have a constraint for fragment that lies at the activity level.
You are right, that could maybe have been solved by Android at the fragment level by introducing loaders local to fragments.

Nevertheless, there might be elegant ways to solve that and preserve a relative de-coupling scheme. For instance, you could create a factory of IDs that would generate "good" IDs for loaders inside fragments and prevent overlapping (id++ would be perfect) :

```
public interface IdFactory {
   public int createId();
}
```

then inside each fragment, when you need a loader :

```
this.newLoaderId = idFactory.createId();
```

The factory could be shared by all fragments using one of the three strategies :

- a singleton. Each fragment will access the IdFactory via

  IdFactory idFactory = DefaultIdFactory.getInstance();
- create a single instance of a class that implements IdFactory, make that instance of that class a data field in your application class an give it a getter. Each fragment will be able to access it using

  IdFactory idFactory = ((MyApplication)getActivity().getApplicationContext() ).getIdFactory();
- create your factories at the activity level. Either activities can implement the IdFactory interface or they can supply an inner class to do it. Each fragment would then access the factory using :

  IdFactory idFactory = getActivity().getIdFactory();
  //or 
   IdFactory idFactory = (IdFactory)getActivity();

The third option is the better as it will follow your exact need and will follow activities life cycles, allowing your factories to be garbage collected.

There are other options like using RoboGuice or Dagger or any other Dependency injection framework, but that is less standard.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, very clear. I decided to follow your suggestion. I am still new to java so i have a question: why can't i just call getActivity().createId() instead of having to cast the object the IdFactory interface? What is the purpose of Interface casting? thanks again

Comment: getActivity will return an Activity and this class doesn't have a createIdFactory method. You need your activity to implement the IdFactory interface and cast your activity into it from within your fragment to be able to access the method, otherwise the compiler won't let you call a method that isn't defined in the type Acitivty itself. If the answer suits your need, please accept it.

Comment: The other answer (by fr1550n) is a better way to go.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can use: [android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getLoaderManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getLoaderManager%28%29)
 to obtain a unique one for each Fragment which means that you can start your ids from zero.

Comment: That returns a LoaderManager not a SupportLoaderManager

Comment: @States It returns `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager`, ergo a **support** LoaderManager (which doesn't *really* exist). The normal Fragment from `android.app.Fragment` returns a `android.app.FragmentManager` (**not** the support implementation). So it's save to use this mehtod.

Comment: Check out the answer by @Snicolas.  As of API22 it appears that while the loader managers might be different (can be seen with enableDebugLogging), the ids when overlapping cause all sorts of issues.  I cannot figure out way to have overlapping ids and I have simply moved to having non-overlapping ids (id ranges per Fragment).

Comment: While one *should* use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getLoaderManager()` for listviews within Fragments, this returns the same LoaderManager as `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088404/difference-between-getloadermanger-and-getactivity-getsupportloadermanager/34139461#34139461