# Difference between getLoaderManger() and getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager() inside v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android

`getLoaderManager()` from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `getSupportLoaderManager()` from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

Do they return the same thing? I couldn't find it in the documentation. If not, which one should be used with the support library from inside a fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They return the exact same thing - a `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager`.

From the source code: [`v4.app.Fragment`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java#Fragment.getLoaderManager%28%29) is actually recalling the host activity:

```
 public LoaderManager getLoaderManager() {
     if (mLoaderManager != null) {
         return mLoaderManager;
     }
     if (mActivity == null) {
         throw new IllegalStateException(...);
     }

     mLoaderManager = mActivity.getLoaderManager(...);
     return mLoaderManager;
 }
```

Your activity is presumably extending [`v4.app.FragmentActivity`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#FragmentActivity.getSupportLoaderManager%28%29) and you can see that `getLoaderManager()` is a private method called also by `getSupportLoaderManager()`:

```
public LoaderManager getSupportLoaderManager() {
    ...
    mLoaderManager = getLoaderManager(...);
    return mLoaderManager;
}
```

So:

- To use `v4.app.Fragment`s, you need to subclass `v4.app.FragmentActivity` (`AppCompatActivity` is just an example);
- Both `v4.app.Fragment.getLoaderManager()` and `v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportLoaderManager()` end up calling the same exact method, `v4.app.FragmentActivity.getLoaderManager()`. I'm pretty sure there is no difference whatshoever between the two.

Comment: Do you have a reference on this? I just tried both, and they seem to be acting differently. `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager()` seems to be coupled with the `activity`. The loader isn't destroyed as long as the `activity` isn't. Whereas, loader started with `getLoaderManager()` in `v4.app.Fragment` seems to be destroyed if the `fragment` is destroyed.

Comment: They surely return a support version of  `android.app.LoaderManager`, which as said is  `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager`. I'm pretty sure the fragment itself is calling `getActivity().getLoaderManager()`, so there shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: Of course the LoaderManager you create is linked with the Fragment / Activity instance you used to instantiate it, so it is true that it might be destroyed if the fragment is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Loader inside the (support.v4.app.)Fragment (e.g. your listview is inside the Fragment, and the loader callback is set to the Fragment) you should use the `getLoaderManager()` of the Fragment, instead of calling `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager()`.

The accepted answer is right that the two return the same thing, but their side effects are different: when you use the `getLoaderManager()` of the Fragment, the `mLoaderManager` of the Fragment is set to point to the Loader Manager returned.  Only then, the support library will know how to take care of managing the loader manager (which in turn manages the loaders) in accordance with the lifecycle of the Fragment.

When the Fragment (but not the activity) is destroyed, the loader will be stopped *only* if you use the Fragment version of `getLoaderManager()`.  If you do the contrary, the loader manager / loader would not know that the fragment was destroyed, and could invoke its callback to call the fragment when loading is finished, etc.

So your observation that they act differently should indeed be correct.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html).

> Do they return the same thing?

Support and Non-support versions of LoadManager do the same thing but they are not on the same package. Basically `getLoaderManager()`  is the partner of `android.app.Fragment` while `getSupportLoaderManager()` is the partner of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. You need to remember that Support library is for Build SDK below 11 therefore you cannot use android.app.Fragment on lower than SDK 11 but you can use Support library in any Build Versions.

This is what getLoadManager returns *I cant zoom the pic*
[image]

And LoaderManagerImpl extends LoaderManager which is part of the Support Library.

[image]

Comment: There is a `getLoaderManager()` in `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` as well. I was talking about that.

Comment: I just want to comment everything although I don't have 50 rep. If it is possible for you to show a screenshot can I see it?

Comment: *There is a getLoaderManager() in android.support.v4.app.Fragment as well* <----

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getLoaderManager()